# How do I perform validation on an api call while submitting form and produce necessary error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My web app is an add-on service to another existing web-app.

Users may sign up to my web-app but first I must check if they are registered on the dependent web app.

I can do so by getting their username/password key and send it as parameters in an API CALL. If the call succeeds it returns their API TOKEN(to be used for further requests) else it returns a 404 error. If I receive the 404 error I'll just handle the exception by putting the error in a flash message.

How do I do this after the form is submitted?

I should generate an error which shows that the user is not registered on the web-app which my web-app depends on.

Comment: What do you mean by "during the form submit"? AFAICT, you'd put this code into either the rails action (which responds to the form-submit with an error message) or into some javascript (so it can be done client-side before the form is sent to rails)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying to `ActiveModel`'s validations you do it yourself.

In your controller action:

```
def sign_in
  # Assuming you issuing an HTTP request (HTTParty or Net::HTTP or your custom API handler)
  @errors = []
  response = MyAPI.sign_in(params[:username], params[:password])

  if response.code == 200
    # all good.. store response's API token for future requests
    # and redirect to success path or render a view...
  else
    @errors << 'Sign in failed, please register on the other app first'  
  end       
end
```

In your views you can easily then check whether `@errors` is empty. If not, display the error messages. You might of course want more fine-grained checks, e.g. responding differently for different failures (40x, 50x).

Comment: I just need the API TOKEN(The result of the apicall) once.I don't need to call the API every sign in, only once then I will save the API Token locally.I just need to get the API TOKEN once, which is on user sign up. I will only allow the user to sign up if his account exists on the other app.

Comment: Well, OK, the logic regarding errors stays the same. Just perform another check to see whether you already have an API token for that user and if you do skip the API call...